Dominated convergence theorem in locally compact groups
In https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~bishop/classes/math638.F20/Grafakos_Classical_Fourier_Analysis.pdf Theorem 1.2.19, the author uses the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem in the context of locally compact groups. Specifically, let $1\leq p<\infty$, and $G$ a locally compact group with left Haar measure $\mu$. Let $g$ a continuous functions supported in a compact set $L$ of $G$, and suppose that $W$ is a relatively compact neighborhood of the identity element $e$. I see why $$|g(h^{-1}x)-g(x)|^p\leq (2||g||_\infty)^p\chi_{W^{-1}L}.$$ But then the author says that $$\int_G |g(h^{-1}x)-g(x)|^pd\mu(x)\to 0,$$ as $h\to e$. This is even a sequence, more like a net i guess, are we really allowed to just use this theorem as in the case of Euclidean Lebesgue spaces? Thank in advance.
